# Perl files seem to combine namespaces without requiring

Tags: perl, cgi-bin

I have a perl file that uses a sub routine (a function) defined in a different module inside the same directory. However, that module is never required in the original file, nor is the subroutine defined anywhere in the file, nor is it called from the module properly.

From my understanding, a subroutine from a module is called like such

```
require "module1.pm";
Module1::greet();
```

However, the file im working with simply goes

```
greet()
```

How is this possible? Is it something to do with "import"? The file im working in is likely a module for a main file somewhere else that requires all the modules, does it work like that? If the subroutine's module is never specified, how do I track it down other than the comb through all the other modules in the directory? I didn't write the code i'm working with, so I'm not familiar with the structure.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to provide functions to other code, and by the design of the whole system, which is quite flexible and fluid, some of them are quite devilous. (It is up to the developer's good practice and taste to choose.)

Consider this bad manner

**main.pl**

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use FindBin qw($RealBin);
use lib $RealBin;          # so we can load from the same directory

use Mod1;

say "In ", __PACKAGE__;

hey_mod2();  # *not* from Mod1
```

In the same directory, `Mod1.pm`

```
package Mod1;

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Mod2;

1;
```

and `Mod2.pm`

```
package Mod2;

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

# Write directly to main:: symbol table
# Just an example of what is possible -- please don't do this
*{main::hey_mod2} = \&greet;

sub greet {
    say "Uninvited hello from ", __PACKAGE__;
}

1;
```

When you run `perl main.pl` it prints

```
In main
Uninvited hello from Mod2
```

So yes, it is possible to push function names into programs even as they don't ask for nor know about it.

If you can provide more detail it may be possible to come up with a reasonable way to work with what you've got, but it is also possible that you may have to account for who calls who from where (etc) by going through files.

Comment: This isn't nearly as bad as it can be.  It's actually kinda simplest way to do it

Comment: I believe my author is using Post and Get forms to pass values through input and select tags inside a form. The form has method = post and action = /cgi-bin/. The application is a web application made using CGI-bin.

Comment: @HarryZ.Huang Thanks, but that doesn't help us explain where function names come from?  The first thing I'd do is to go carefully through documentation for libraries that are included (`use`-ed) and see whether those functions are in fact there.  If not, go through custom modules that are included and see what they do and include.  Etc. You can always track it down from code.  Or show us the troubling code -- and what is included in that program.  (One includes modules by `use ModName`, or indeed by `require ModName;` at runtime -- but normally you want `use`).